# Custom md chips on basis of condition

Tags: angular-material

I am using md-chips in my application but I am not able to customize chips on basis of certain condition. Lets suppose I have two chips and one of them I want readonly ans other one as removable. But when I tried readonly it is making both the chips as readonly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not apparently possible with a single  instance in ng-material. However there is a workaround depending on what you are trying to accomplish that can allow you to have the same set of chips displayed in different positions with different conditions.

What you can do is have two different `<md-chips>` instances on your page with the same `ng-model` so that they both match each other.

One `md-chips` can have readonly set to true and the other can be set to writable and removable. This can be useful if you are trying to display perhaps a "Selected Chips" or "current chips" in one place and the same chips somewhere else in an editing area.